# Incorrect format after parsing string HTML in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

While parsing I use this code

```
  func encode() -> String{
        var newStr = String(utf8String: self.cString(using: .utf8)!)
        newStr = newStr!.removingPercentEncoding

        guard let data = String(utf8String: self.cString(using: .utf8)!)?.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return newStr!
        }     
        guard let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding:  String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil) else {
            return newStr!
        }
       return  attributedString.string
    }
```

the problem is that it removes the \n.
So I do not display the text correctly

Comment: TBH, you are doing very strange things with `cString` there. It's hard to just look at the code. Can you please at least debug it and find after which line the newline is lost?

Comment: Not related but the double *String round-trip* is horrible. Converting to cString and back to String is nonsense. Replace the first two lines and the entire first `guard` statement with `let data = Data(self.utf8)` and replace `return newStr!` with `return self`

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to accomplish? then it might be easier to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html`

depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may just ignore that fact or replace `"\n"` with something else in your `String`.